# How to insert a column of huge dimension with Pandas in a faster way?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes, `df_A` with 2 columns `'col_1'` and `'col_2'`, and `df_B` with 1 column `'col_1'`.
The name of `'col_1'` is actually tha same in both dataframes.
Moreover, `df_A` and `df_B` have about 300k and 80k rows respectively.

What I want to do is to create a new column `'col_3'` in `df_B` which elements are the first element of `df_A['col_2']`, after a sorting (numerically or alfabetically), when the elements of `df_A['col_1']` and `df_B['col_1']` coincide.

For example: if `'x'` is an element of `df_B['col_1']`, and `df_A[df_A['col_1']==x]` is like:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | A |
| x | B |
| x | B |

what I want to report for `df_B['col_3']` is `'A'`.

I tried codes similar to the following:

```
df_A.sort_values(by=['col_2'])

x = [df_A[df_A['col_1']==df_B.at[i,'col_1']]['col_2'].iloc[0] for i in df_B.index]

df_B,insert(1,'col_3',x)
```

and they work but, given the huge amount of rows, they take too much time to run (about an half hour).
I'd like to use a merging, but I don't know how to use it correctly.
What code can I write for a faster run?

Comment: Use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: I found it:

df_temp = df_A.sort_values(by=['col_2'])
df_temp = df_temp.drop_duplicates(subset='col_1', inplace=True)
df_B = df_B.merge(df_temp, on='col_1')